# How to change second column on specific item

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to change second column on specific item
my script

```
                    foreach (ListView item in lvVictumes.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Name == "devid")
                    {
                        item.SubItems[1].Text = "13";
                    }
                }
```

Error   CS1061  'ListView' does not contain a definition for 'SubItems' and no extension method 'SubItems' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: SubItems is a property of ListViewItem

Answer (score 0):

The [`ListView.Items` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items(v=vs.110).aspx) is a collection of `ListViewItem` (which has a `SubItems` property), not `ListView` (which doesn't have `SubItems`).

Fix your `foreach` line, and the rest should work.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvVictumes.Items)
{
    if (item.Name == "devid")
    {
        item.SubItems[1].Text = "13";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not confusing the Windows Forms `ListViewItem` with the WPF `ListView`?
WPF's `ListView` does not have SubItems.